# Cannot open .xls file with Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have .xls files emailed to me. When I open the file with Power Bi it comes with this error: "external table is not in the expected format".

If I save file as .xlsx then I can open it with with no issues.

The files come every day.

I cannot always manually change the format to .xlsx.

if this can be automated that would solve my issue.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Without looking at your file, it's very hard to give you a diagnosis on your issue. you should definitely consider reaching out to whoever is in charge of dumping those files and ask to replace them with CSV files as this will not only solve your problem but also make it more efficient. Note that .xls files are created on versions prior to 2007.

Comment: this might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-access-database-errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use a powershell script, that converts every .xls file into an .xlsx file and run it as a scheduled task (if they are placed in the same directory). Here's a sample https://gist.github.com/gabceb/954418

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple Microsoft flow to change the extension (File Name) each time a file arrives in an email as below :

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I ve tried that. The file extension changes but the format stays the same.

Comment: So did the file open ?

Answer (score 0):

When I ve had a closer look I found the file is in html format with .xls extension.

I was able to open it in Power Bi.